# What could be wrong with Lenovo ThinkPad X390 Keyboard; specifically the R shift button?

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad

My keyboard, now happening for 2 times behaves as if the R shift key is pressed as shows on the on screen keyboard. I have updated my keyboard drivers, I have switched off sticky keys and toggle keys in the settings but the issue is somehow resolved. however what stroke me most is that it came back within a period of 2 weeks after solving the issue previously.

I am stuck as to whether it will come back again or not. What could the problem be such that incase it happens again, I know how to fix it once and for all?

I have a Windows 11 64-bit i7 Core 8th Gen 16GB RAM and 1TB computer.

Comment: If a key resembles to be stuck, you should also take into account that the key might stuck physically. — Just a drop of Coke or any other drink  with sugar or some sticky parts of other food below the key cap might keep the key stuck for some time and release it later on.